# Reading any file as binary in C++?

Tags: c++, file, stream, ifstream

How might I read any file type as binary in C++? So far, I've been able to read .txt files in binary using `std::bitset` like so:

```
std::ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("example.txt", std::ios::binary);
while (getline (myfile, line) ) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i<line.size(); ++i) {
        std::bitset<8> a = std::bitset<8>(line[i]); //convert every character to binary, save it in a

        std::cout<<((char)std::bitset<8>(a).to_ulong())<<'\n';
    }
}
```

In the first line, how might I read a file like `sound.mp3` or `word.docx` as a binary file? I understand that in they really just are binary files, but how can I read them as such?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a computer program. All files are binary...

Comment: Look up "transform" in the C++ standard library. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/?kw=transform

Comment: @fredrik How do I read them as such?

Comment: You can use `read` to read from a binary file to a block of memory and then convert each char to bits as you do above .

Comment: @GiliL. Could you give me an example please?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: @GiliL. Thanks, but I'd still appreciate an example which took, for example, an mp3 file and `read` it into a block of memory.

Comment: @GiliL. `read` does not work on an mp3 using `myfile.read (memblock, size);` where `memblock` is an array of `char` with size `size`. You get all sorts of decoding errors through Sublime Text, and when run through the terminal, the terminal throws up.

Comment: Of course you cannot print the chars as this is not a text file. You can convert the chars to hex or bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By casting from a block of memory of chars to binary, you can read a file as binary.

```
std::streampos size;
char * memblock;

std::ifstream myfile ("sound.mp3", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
//ios::ate puts the reader at the end of the file
if (file.is_open())
{
    size = myfile.tellg();
    memblockChar = new char [size];
    myfile.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
    myfile.read (memblockChar, size);
    myfile.close();

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        std::cout << (((std::bitset<8>)memblockChar[i]).to_ulong()) << '\n';
    }
    delete[] memblockChar;
}
else std::cout<<"Unable to open file"<<std::endl;
```

This could be used in a main method, or anywhere else.